# Why does the return type of tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() change when it's called using the key word "with"?

Tags: python-3.x, temporary-files

I need help to understand the return type of tempfile.TemporaryDirectory().

```
import tempfile

temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
print(type(temp_dir)) # It yields: <class 'tempfile.TemporaryDirectory'>

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    print(type(temp_dir)) # It yields: <class 'str'>
```

As we can see what listed above, the return type of tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() changed when it's called using the key word "with". Can someone please explain it to me why?

Just as a comparison, the return type of subprocess.Popen() does not change when it's called using the key word "with" or not. This is an expected behavior.

```
import subprocess

cmd="ls -l"
response = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(type(response)) # It yields: <class 'subprocess.Popen'>

with subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as response:
    print(type(response)) # It yields: <class 'subprocess.Popen'>
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to format the code

Answer (score 2):

When you use `with` statement it actually calls `__enter__` method, so it is not the same as assignment. It also calls `__exit__` after code within `with` is done.

When you use `TemporaryDirectory` in `with` statement it automatically handles directory remove after leaving `with` statement, so you don't need to worry about that. However when you use it like

```
temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
```

then it does not know when to delete this directory and you have to do it yourself - hence it gives you handle to that dir instead of path only.